# adding space before each item in itemize

Tags: spacing, lists, indentation, itemize

I would like to add some space before each `\item` in `begin{itemize}`

When i try doing something like this

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \hspace {5cm} Sweden
\item \hspace {5cm} Germany
\end{itemize}
```

The output i get is something like this

```
•                Sweden
•                Germany
```

As it can be seen the space are added after the bullets.

Any recommendation?? Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a dimension defined for doing just that: `\itemindent`.

```
\begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemindent}{5cm}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\end{itemize}
```

Note that `\itemindent` is reset at the start of the `itemize` environment, so you need to adjust it *after* `\begin{itemize}`. If you'd like the same indentation on all your lists, you could define a new environment which defines this:

```
\newenvironment{indentitemize}{%
\begin{itemize}%
\addtolength{\itemindent}{5cm}%
}
{%
\end{itemize}%
}
```

and use it just like a normal `itemize` environment. (This I havent tested, but I assume it works...)

**A complete example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is some text before the list.
\begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemindent}{5cm}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @Kishorepandey: No problem - that's what this site is for =)

Comment: @Kishorepandey: When revisiting this post, I thought of a way to further improve the way to do this - define a new environment that takes care of the indentation, so you get the same across your document. See my updated answer for details =)

Comment: @Paul Gaborit: What did you do to get the better picture? Manually crop the pdf, or something else?

Comment: @Kishorepandey: Note also the answer from Werner below - if you're using the `enumitem` package, this functionality is built-in already.

Comment: @TomasLycken I added `\pagestyle{empty}` then I used `pdfcrop` (via a script of my own that converts PDF to PNG).

Answer (score 9):

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) allows for local redefinitions of lists via a key-value approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \hspace {5cm} Sweden
\item \hspace {5cm} Germany
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[itemindent=5cm]
\item Sweden
\item Germany
\end{itemize}
\end{document}​
```

These localized alterations can also be made global using `\setlist`. See the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) (section **5 Global settings**, p 9).

Comment: Can we add space only before the first line of each item?

Comment: @alper: Yes. [Here are some options](https://pastebin.com/raw/TNM440ZD).